# Angular 4 Router return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I try to make a function that using `Router.navigate({})`

Importing Router:

```
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';
```

The class with the functions and the constructor:

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router:Router,private renderer: Renderer2,public but2: ElementRef, public but1: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  nvgt(lc){
    this.router.navigate([ lc ]);
  }
  navigator(loc) {
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.but1.nativeElement.querySelector('#but1'),'animation','fadeoutdown 1s both');
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.but2.nativeElement.querySelector('#but2'),'animation','fadeoutup 1s both');
  window.setInterval(this.nvgt,1500,loc)
  }
}
```

The component HTML(2 buttons):

```
<button #but1 id="but1" (click)="navigator('/questions')" mat-raised-button>Search for my next phone</button>
<hr data-content="OR">
<button #but2 id="but2" (click)="navigate('/inputphone')" mat-raised-button>Search specific phone</button>
```

When I click the next error found in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
    at HomeComponent.nvgt (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/home/home.component.ts:25)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4940)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:495)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:484)
    at timer (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:2065)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lost the reference to `this`, a typical problem with lots of guys in JS. Change this line:

```
window.setInterval(this.nvgt,1500,loc)
```

To

```
window.setInterval(() => this.nvgt(loc),1500)
```

You see, lambdas do not have  a context, unlike typical js functions (you pass a reference of a method in your code), and rather stick to the context they have been called in (a class or another function).

Comment: Consider marking this question as answered so people do not waste time / know that they can find an answer to a similar issue here

Comment: Sorry, but the first button works properly, but the 2nd button throw this error:`ERROR TypeError: _co.navigate is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomeComponent.html:3)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13581)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15090)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14677)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9990)
    at eval (core.js:10611)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you just mistyped the name of the function. It's `navigator`, not `navigate`

Comment: Ahh, the problem is:
In the first button the event is `(click)="navigator('/questions')"`
And in the 2nd button the event is `(click)="navigate('/questions')"`

Answer (score 1):

`btn2` click function should be `navigator`

```
<button #but2 id="but2" (click)="navigator('/inputphone')" mat-raised-button>Search specific phone</button>
```